# Creating ComboBox in Win32 not working properly

Tags: winapi, combobox, controls, parent-child, window-messages

I am creating a Win32 ComboBox for the first time. And I have a problem here.

When calling `CreateWindow` for the ComboBox, it calls the WndProc callback function again with the `WM_CREATE` message, so what happens is the ComboBox makes a child ComboBox, again and again like recursion.

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <random> 
#include <time.h> 
#include <string>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HINSTANCE g_hInst; 
LPCTSTR lpszClass = L"ComboBox"; 
const WCHAR *items[] = { L"Apple", L"Orange", L"Melon", L"Grape", L"Strawberry" };
HWND hwnd;

enum COMMAND_ID {
    COMMAND_ID_CONTROL_COMBO_0
};

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszCmdParam, int nCmdShow)
{ 
    srand(time(NULL));
    g_hInst = hInstance;

    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = lpszClass;
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    RegisterClass(&wndClass);

    hwnd = CreateWindow(
        lpszClass,
        lpszClass,  
        WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,   
        NULL,       
        (HMENU)NULL,        
        hInstance,      
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    MSG msg;
    while (true)
    {   
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break; 
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
} 

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{   
    static HWND hCombo;
    static WCHAR str[128];

    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {
            hCombo = CreateWindow(
                L"combobox",
                NULL,
                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_BORDER | CBS_DROPDOWN,
                10, 10, 200, 200,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)COMMAND_ID_CONTROL_COMBO_0,
                g_hInst,
                NULL);

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            {
                SendMessage(hCombo, CB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)items[i]);
            }

            SendMessage(hCombo, CB_SETCURSEL, 0, NULL);
        }
        break;

        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            switch (LOWORD(wparam))
            {
                case COMMAND_ID_CONTROL_COMBO_0:
                    switch (HIWORD(wparam))
                    {
                        case CBN_SELCHANGE:
                        {
                            int iCurSel = SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETCURSEL, NULL, NULL);
                            SendMessage(hCombo, CB_GETLBTEXT, iCurSel, (LPARAM)str);
                            SetWindowText(hWnd, str);
                        }
                        break;

                        case CBN_EDITCHANGE:
                            GetWindowText(hCombo, str, 128);
                            SetWindowText(hWnd, str);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wparam, lparam);
}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

I tried to put some boolean flag to execute `WM_CREATE` only once, and it works, I mean only creating one ComboBox without any child in it.

But, it just looked like only a white window with a border mark, there's no arrow button or anything to dropdown page that the ComboBox is supposed to have.

This recursive case never happened when I was creating different controls like Buttons, CheckBoxes, ListBoxes, etc.

And the ComboBox created doesn't look like it has the proper shape, too.

Hope I am just missing something simple.

Comment: Because your main window and child window has same class name, so has same wndproc.

Comment: The code is incomprehensible. If you want people to help you out, you need to make it *easy* for them to see your problem. This, though, looks much like an [IOCCC](https://www.ioccc.org/) contestant, and doesn't even match a category in the better known [shapes of a program](https://youtu.be/P2lxGnbDkDI). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65271303/edit) your question to fix that.

Comment: Does the answer work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When calling CreateWindow for the ComboBox, **it calls the WndProc
> callback function again with the WM_CREATE message**, so what happens
> is the ComboBox makes a child ComboBox, again and again like
> recursion.

[`WM_CREATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-create) message is sent to the window procedure of the new window after the window is created. Your first `WM_CREATE` message is generated by this line `hwnd = CreateWindow()`. Then you create another window in first `WM_CREATE` message, so it will generate second `WM_CREATE` message. Because you use the same registered class (`"ComboBox"` / `"combobox"`, it is not case sensitive) to create all these windows, all of them use the same one window procedure. So you receive `WM_CREATE` message again and again until `CreateWindow` fail to create a window and return `NULL`.

> But, it just looked like only a white window with a border mark,
> there's no arrow button or anything to dropdown page that the ComboBox
> is supposed to have.

The root cause is you register a class with the same name as the existing system class: `"ComboBox"` / `"combobox"`. This new registered class override the existing one. It is just a common window instead of a predefined Combobox control as @RemyLebeau pointed out.

> An application can register an application local class having the same
> name as a system class. This replaces the system class in the context
> of the application but does not prevent other applications from using
> the system class.

Refer to "[How the System Locates a Window Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes#how-the-system-locates-a-window-class)".

To make the Combobox display in expected shape, what you need to do is changing the `lpszClass` to a non-predefined one, for example, like `"SimpleComboBoxExample"`.

It is suggested to use predefined macro of **Combobox Class Name**: [`WC_COMBOBOX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/common-control-window-classes) instead of `L"combobox"`.

More reference: "[How to Create a Simple Combo Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-a-simple-combo-box)".

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually creating a Win32 ComboBox at all. You are registering your own class named `"ComboBox"`, and then creating a window of that class, which creates a window of that class, which creates a window of that class, and so on recursively.

You need to change this line:

```cpp
LPCTSTR lpszClass = L"ComboBox";
```

To a different unique name, such as `"MyWindowClass"`.

---

On a side note, your message loop is structured wrong. It should look like this instead:

```cpp
MSG msg;
while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}
```

And in your `WndProc()`, the `return 0;` statement *underneath* the `WM_COMMAND` handler is in the wrong place. It needs to be moved *inside* of the `WM_COMMAND` handler instead:

```cpp
case WM_COMMAND:
{
    switch (...)
    {
        ...
    }
    return 0; // <-- moved here
}
//return 0; // <-- from here
```